# Why is the integral test only for positive decreasing functions?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

The way that the integral test is taught is that

> If f is a continuous, positive and decreasing function where $f(n)=a_n$ on the interval [1,∞), then. the improper integral $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ and the infinite series $\sum_1^\infty a_n$. either both converge or both diverge.

However I am having quite a hard time building an intuition for this, say we have the infinite sum:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\ln(n)}{n^3}$$
And we compare it to the function
$$f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x^3}$$

At the upper bound:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\ln(n)}{n^3}< \int^n_1\frac{\ln(x)}{x^3}dx$$
Solving by parts
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\ln(n)}{n^3}< \left[\frac{-\ln(x)}{2x^2} \right]^n_1 +\int^n_1\frac{1}{2x^3}$$
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\ln(n)}{n^3}< \frac{-\ln(n)}{2n^2} +\left[\frac{-1}{4x^2}\right]^n_1$$
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\ln(n)}{n^3}< \frac{-\ln(n)}{2n^2} -\frac{1}{4n^2} +\frac{1}{4}$$

Then by using L'Hôpital's rule
$$\lim \limits_{n  \to \infty} \frac{-\ln(n)}{2n^2}=\lim \limits_{n  \to \infty}\frac{-1}{4n^2}=0$$

Hence the integral converges to $\frac{1}{4}$ and so the sum also converges.

However looking at the graph of the function and by differentiating it it is apparent that the function only retains positive and decreasing for the interval for $x>e^{\frac{1}{3}}$

[image: graph1]

Yet the integral test seems to be still working properly over the greater interval of $x>1$ which contains both the increasing and decreasing parts of the function.

By drawing rectangles of unit width touching the function at the right corners it becomes apparent that for values $x>e^{\frac{1}{3}}$ the rectangles estimate the upper bound but for values less than this interval from $e^{\frac{1}{3}}>x>1$ they instead approximate the lower bound.

[image: graph2]

Why then does this test still apparently work and would this extend from $x=0$ to $x=\infty$ as well?

Comment: About your last question: How would you define $\log$ on $(-\infty,0]$?

Comment: @Gary Ah my bad I meant to say for the interval $(0,1|$ where the function is both negative and increasing, I will fix the question.

Comment: I would not use the same symbol for the index of summation and the upper limit of integration. Also, for what $n$ does that upper bound for the sum hold? When using L'Hôpital's rule, suddenly an $x$ appears and the limit operation disappears.

Comment: @Gary $\lim \limits_{n  \to \infty} \frac{-\ln(n)}{2n^2}$ $\lim \limits_{n  \to \infty} \frac{-\frac{1}{x}}{4n}$  $\lim \limits_{n  \to \infty} \frac{-1}{4n^2}=0$

Comment: You missed the equality signs and again used $x$ instead of $n$.

Comment: But again, in $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\log n}}{{n^3 }}}  < \int_1^n {\frac{{\log x}}{{x^3 }}dx} $ what is $n$ on the right-hand side? For example $n=1$ would not work.

Comment: It is meant to be the upper bound of the integral which then approaches infinity although I now see how that is confusing, I shall fix it.\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if, for some $N\in\Bbb N$, the series $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n$ converges. In other words, the first terms of the series do not matter when we are dealing with the proeblem of deciding whether a series converges or not. So, when we use the integral test, all that matters about $f$ is that, for some $a>0$, its restriction to $[a,\infty)$ is positive, decreasing and convergent to $0$. What happens to the left of that $a$ does not matter.

Comment: The interval from $x=1$ to $x=e^\frac{1}{3}$ is still within the limits of the sum however, and at this interval the function is not decreasing, would this have any major consequence?

Comment: @Filthyscrub You can ignore the first few terms of the sum. Convergence depends on the tail of the series not the first finitely many terms.

Comment: It has no consequence whatsoever for decidint whether the series converges or diverges.

Comment: Also, note that "first few terms" that you ignore could be the first seventy billion. If you're only worried about convergence, and not the actual value, nobody even bothers to look at the starting value of the index.